# python opencv cv2.waitkey error

Tags: python, opencv, traceback

i'm trying to test the following code of the *[getting started page](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html#py-display-image)*:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2   
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg', 0)
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitkey(0)&0xFF
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But i got this error:

```
init done 
opengl support available 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "showimg.py", line 5, in <module>
    cv2.waitkey(0)&0xFF
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'waitkey'
Violación de segmento
```

I executed the examples that comes with the opencv installation, and they run correctly. Also, the last example that use the Matplotlib works fine.

¿Any idea of the error?, ¿any suggestion?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'waitkey'

Try  `cv2.waitKey` in place of `cv2.waitkey`.  Capitalization counts.

Answer (score 1):

```
cv2.waitKey()
```

This syntax works. In the open parentheses add time.

Comment: This is basically the same answer as the accepted one from five years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try waitKey() instead of waitkey(),It worls fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
'module' object has no attribute 'waitkey'
```

For solving this problem you should use this code:

[image]

'waitKey' with capital K, it will solve your problem.